# Magento update order state via SOAP

Tags: magento

I need to update order state remotely. Is it possible to update it via SOAP? 
I know about "sales_order.addComment", but it updates only status not state.

My version is CE 1.7.0.2

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As i know we can not get state about order Also you can get only information about an order and add a comment to it.

You cannot `edit` or `delete` an order.

You have to create your own API if you need that. See this link to see what is possible with the API: Magento Core API - [Mage Sales](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api#mage_sales)

hope you can understand this concern.

Answer (score 0):

Currently magento do NOT have a soap api to update order state, but you could create you own custom api take a look @ Creating a [Custom API or Extending the Core API](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/create_your_own_api.html)

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a necro answer here, but one basic strategy might involve a basic cron task that runs every few minutes.

Since you can update the status via the API, you might create a couple new custom statuses that you update as needed. The first status would mark an order as being ready to be consumed by your logic, the second status marks an order as done being consumed.

Then your cron script could just check for orders that are done being consumed which you can then use standard Magento standard model operations to update the state.